# Is there a way to hook into the Foundation off-canvas close and open even to change the menu-icon

Tags: css, angularjs, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using angular-foundation and trying to find a way to change the off-canvas menu icon when you open/close the menu. Currently I use:

```
<a class="right-off-canvas-toggle menu-icon"><span></span></a>
```

I'd like to replace the "menu-icon" with my own class, but I'm not sure how to hook into the close method. I tried adding an ng-click, but that won't fire on the close since an `<a>` tag is used to overlay the rest of the page for the close function. I figured based on that, using the off canvas would be the best method.

Comment: What version of Foundation?

Comment: It's a little hard to understand your question. You can change any of the icons by modifying or overriding the ZURB Foundation CSS. You can just inspect these icons to get the classes that you would need to modify. The same is for the close box used in modals, alerts, etc. If you are talking about the huge <a> that acts to close the offcanvas then it is not clear why you want to modify that. If you update and clarify your question I am happy to answer.

Comment: I'm looking to change the icon to indicate an open/closed state visually when it is open and closed. Overall, I'm looking for a way to do this through Foundation. If the framework doesn't support it, then I'll leave it be. Modifying the open close state would probably have to trigger through the function that the <a> tag fires.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so hooking into the `open.fndtn.offcanvas` and `close.fndtn.offcanvas` events, something like this:

```
$(document).on('open.fndtn.offcanvas', '[data-offcanvas]', function() {
    var off_canvas_icon = $(this).find('.right-off-canvas-toggle');

    off_canvas_icon.removeClass('menu-icon').addClass('close-icon');
});

$(document).on('close.fndtn.offcanvas', '[data-offcanvas]', function() {
    var off_canvas_icon = $(this).find('.right-off-canvas-toggle');

    off_canvas_icon.removeClass('close-icon').addClass('menu-icon');
});
```